# Sum of an infinite series series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've determined the convergence of this alternating series. It converges absolutely. The series is 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{(n-1)}.
$$
I'm stuck on how to find the sum of this series. It could be a mental block but I just can't think of a way to determine the sum.

Comment: This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Looks to me a geometric series with a rate equal to $-0.25$. There is a formula to calculate that sum.

Answer (score 1):

The other submitter had the general idea.
The series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^{n-1}$$ is a geometric series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a{r}^{n-1}}=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+...$$
where the first term is $a$ and the common ratio is $r$.
This geometric series always converges if $\left|r\right|\lt 1$, where in this case the sum is given by:
$$S_\infty=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Comparing coefficients, it can be seen that $a=2$ and $r=\frac{-1}{4}$.

Therefore, since $\left|r\right|=\frac{1}{4}\lt 1$, the sum of the series is given by:
$$S_\infty=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{2}{1-\frac{-1}{4}}=\frac{8}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1} = \left. \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} \right|_{-1/4} = \left. \frac{1}{1-x} \right|_{-1/4} = \frac{4}{5}
$$
Since ($|x| < 1$)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Comment: There is a $2$ upfront...

Comment: @imranfat I think OP can figure that out easily.

Comment: That is also true...

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n q^i = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}
$$